# Dynamic Text depending on output of a manipulate

Tags: manipulate, text

So I am looking for a way to calculate and show dynamically as text the `x-Axis-value` of the Intercept of those two curves.

```
Manipulate[Plot[s*(1 + r/12)^(y) + m*((1 + r/12)^y - 1)/(r/12), {y, 1, 36},
GridLines -> {None, {g}}, PlotRange -> {0, g*1.1}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
AxesLabel -> {"Months", "Fr"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Saving Calculator"], 
{{s, 100, "Initial Savings"}, 0,   10000, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{r, 0.05, "Interest Rate"}, 0, 0.1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{m, 50, "Monthly Savings"}, 0, 500, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{g, 5000, "Saving Goal"}, 1000, 100000, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Its about the intercept of the red to the blue curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should the intercept be shown on the plot?

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Callout[s*(1 + r/12)^(y) + m*((1 + r/12)^y - 1)/(r/12), 
      StringJoin["Intercept=", 
       ToString[#]], #] &@((Solve[
          s*(1 + r/12)^(y) + m*((1 + r/12)^y - 1)/(r/12) == g, y] // 
         Flatten // Values)[[1]])], {y, 1, 36}, 
  GridLines -> {None, {g}}, PlotRange -> {0, g*1.1}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  AxesLabel -> {"Months", "Fr"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Saving Calculator"], {{s, 100, "Initial Savings"}, 0, 
  10000, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 0.05, "Interest Rate"}, 
  0, 0.1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m, 50, "Monthly Savings"},
   0, 500, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{g, 5000, "Saving Goal"}, 
  1000, 100000, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Intercept in plot]

Or be shown separately?

```
   Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[
    s*(1 + r/12)^(y) + m*((1 + r/12)^y - 1)/(r/12), {y, 1, 36}, 
    GridLines -> {None, {g}}, PlotRange -> {0, g*1.1}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
    AxesLabel -> {"Months", "Fr"}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     "Saving Calculator"], (Solve[
        s*(1 + r/12)^(y) + m*((1 + r/12)^y - 1)/(r/12) == g, y] // 
       Flatten // Values)[[1]]}], {{s, 100, "Initial Savings"}, 0, 
  10000, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 0.05, "Interest Rate"}, 
  0, 0.1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m, 50, "Monthly Savings"},
   0, 500, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{g, 5000, "Saving Goal"}, 
  1000, 100000, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Intercept below]

P.S. these could definitely be optimized, but should do the trick.  Assigning the equation to a variable should make things nicer